# Set `LOG_*` options in Python `logging.handlers.SysLogHander`

Tags: python, logging, syslog

With `syslog.openlog`, we can set some log options like `LOG_NDELAY`, `LOG_NOWAIT` which are defined in `<syslog.h>`. I was looking for the way to set this kind of log options on `logging.handlers.SysLogHander`.

I found that `LOG_CONS` and `LOG_PERROR` can be implemented with additional `logging.handers`. `LOG_NDELAY` is already set, because the connection is opened when the handler is instantiated.

I don't really care of `LOG_NOWAIT`, because mainly I use Linux.

Then, how can I set `LOG_ODELAY` or `LOG_PID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source for `syslog.openlog`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/122e88a8354e3f75aeaf6211232dac88ac296d54/Modules/syslogmodule.c#L147), it directly passes the option integer to [`openlog(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/openlog).

Diving deeper, glibc's [`openlog`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/misc/syslog.c#L408) calls [`openlog_internal`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/misc/syslog.c#L334), which just sets it to the [`LogStat`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/misc/syslog.c#L338) global.

So, let's look at the flags you require in the `openlog(3)` docs:

> `LOG_ODELAY`: The converse of LOG_NDELAY; opening of the connection is delayed until syslog() is called. (This is the default, and need not be specified.)

This seems only relevant if you *use* `openlog()` in the first place, which `SysLogHandler` does not do; it simply [connects to the syslog over UDP](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L797).

You could implement your own `SyslogFormatter`, which does use `syslog.openlog()` and `syslog.syslog()` and pass all the flags your heart desires – the reason the stdlib doesn't do this, I imagine, is that it's not portable, as the `syslog` module might not be available on e.g. Windows.

> `LOG_PID`: Include PID with each message.

This is implemented in glibc [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/misc/syslog.c#L206-L207).

```
if (LogStat & LOG_PID)
    fprintf (f, "[%d]", (int) __getpid ());
```

This is easy to implement, as [`logging` already logs process IDs by default](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L79) and [exposes it to formatters](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L463).

So simply set your formatter string to

```
"[%(process)s] %(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s"
```

instead of the default

```
"%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s"
```

Comment: I end up with `os.getpid()`, but `%(process)s` is much better. Thanks!